# how to change sealed class method by static class or another way?

Tags: c#, static, overriding, sealed

I want to override a method of the **Sealed Class** from a **static class**.

#### For example:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm MyMethod from MyClass");
    }
}

public sealed class MySealedClass : MyClass
{
    public override void MyMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm MyMethod from MySealedClass");
    }
}
```

The **MyClass** have a virtual method by name **MyMethod**.

In the sealed class this method has been override for self and i want to be written that again for another job by this static class:

```
public static class ClassManager
{
    public static void MyMethod(this MySealedClass msc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm MyMethod from ClassManager");
    }
}
```

Now, we call that static method's from **Program** class to run it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new MySealedClass().MyMethod();
    }
}
```

But this result called **MySealedClass** methods not called my static class method's !!

> > I'm MyMethod from MySealedClass

Please help me, how to change sealed class method by static class or another way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't possible. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx):

> An extension method with the same name and signature as an interface or class method **will never be called**. At compile time, **extension methods always have lower priority than instance methods** defined in the type itself. In other words, if a type has a method named Process(int i), and you have an extension method with the same signature, the compiler will always bind to the instance method.

From the C# spec:

> The preceding rules (the set of rules specified in the spec) mean that **instance methods take precedence over extension methods**, that extension methods available in inner namespace declarations take precedence over extension methods available in outer namespace declarations, and that extension methods declared directly in a namespace take precedence over extension methods imported into that same namespace with a using namespace directive.

You'll have to invoke the method via your static class, and not as an extension method.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that.Extensions methods are considered only if there is no method with that signature in your type.

You need to call your `static` method explicitly:

```
ClassManager.MyMethod(new MySealedClass());
```